# UISearchController search bar width not changing

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Ran through a quick tutorial with search bars and figured that I could use `searchBar.sizeToFit()` to autosize the search bar, however the right end of the search bar still extends off of the screen.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

     var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
         searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
         searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
         searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
         tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
         definesPresentationContext = true
    }}
```

I've tried to manually set the frame with something like `searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)` but the width remained off of the screen. The search bar does not exist in the storyboard, however the tableView does.

Comment: You are using autolayout?

Comment: Why doesn't the search bar exist in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Needed to set autolayout constraints for the tableView that the search bar was a part of. Setting these fixed the sizing issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Auto layout, then use leading and trailing edges instead of width constraints.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
     Just click on Pin option given below and select top,leading(left) and trailing(right) constraints, then click on Add 3 constraints. Make sure "Constraint to margin" checkbox is unchecked. If the constraints satisfy, There will be no warning. Try changing the background color of your search bar to see its position on the screen.

Comment: If you still find problem, send me the zip file of your app/project.

Comment: The search bar doesn't exist on the storyboard. I'll try setting up the autolayout programmatically.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant, you can't set a UISearchController to your own SearchBar, it comes with a built in one

Answer (score 0):

If setting up auto layout constraints doesn't fix the problem, try calling `searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` rather than `viewDidLoad()`. This may help if the search bar is contained in a view other than the table header view.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4, works for all types of ViewControllers**

After countless hours of trial and error here's what I came up for those who want to use it in code:

1. Set delegate

   class SearchDatasourceController: UIViewController , UISearchBarDelegate { }
2. Set a customTitleView and the searchBar

IMPORTANT: set their frame

```
lazy var customTitleView: UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 44)
    view.frame = frame
    return view
  }()

  lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    (searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField)?.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 230, g: 230, b: 230)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 44)
    searchBar.frame = frame
    return searchBar
  }()
```

3. in viewDidLoad add the customTitleView that holds the searchBar

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

   ```
   customTitleView.addSubview(searchBar)
   navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView
   searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
   ```

   }
4. add delegate method to listen for searches

   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       print(searchText)
     }
5. make sure you present your view controller on the navigation stack

   func handleSearchBarButtonItemTapped() {
       let controller = SearchDatasourceController()
       navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
     }